# transgendered / hermaphrodite symbol in base R plot (and other rare unicode glyphs - macOs font problem)

Tags: r, macos, plot, unicode, fonts

I want to use male/female/transgendered/hermaphrodite symbols in base R plot.

This works for me with male and female symbols (male example below).

```
a = '\u2642'   # unicode for male (female = '\u2640')
plot(1, 1, pch = a)
```

[image: male]

With hermaphrodite/transgendered, I get a square.

```
a <- '\u26a5'  # unicode for hermaphrodite/transgendered 
plot(1, 1, pch = a)
```

[image: hermaphrodite fail]

```
> a
[1] "⚥"
```

According to what I had read elsewhere, this seemed like it could be a macOs-specific problem. Many other unicodes also failed and gave me the same square.

Comment: `plot(1, 1, pch = a, family = "Arial Unicode MS")` gets some unicode to work unlike with default font family setting. However, hermaphrodite/transgendered symbol does not work with this workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by installing fonts that support transgendered/hermaphrodite unicode. A list of fonts reportedly supporting U+26A5 could be found in the link below.

https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/26a5/fontsupport.htm

I tried using DejaVu Sans (worked), Symbola (worked), and Code2000 (the version I installed did not work - seemingly without a working hermaphrodite symbol). These were downloaded from various sites on the internet and installed with Font Book. Here's a code with a usable font.

```
a <- '\u26a5'  # unicode for hermaphrodite/transgendered 
plot(1, 1, pch = a, family = "DejaVu Sans")
```

[image]

Here, pch could be replaced with likes of main, xlab, ylab, text, etc. There is no need for Cairo - a code for base R shown below works fine.

```
jpeg("~/Desktop/test2a.jpeg")
a <- '\u26a5' 
plot(1, 1, main = a, family = "Symbola")
dev.off()
```

Hermaphrodite unicode is supported by few fonts. For most things, Arial Unicode MS works fine. List of characters and glyphs with Arial Unicode MS (38,917 characters and 38,917 glyphs).

http://zuga.net/articles/unicode-all-characters-supported-by-the-font-arial-unicode-ms/

Answer (score 0):

This is an encoding issue that seems to happen on MacOS or Linux. The solution I find for plotting unicode characters is to use the `cairo` package.

```
cairo_pdf("~/Desktop/test2.pdf")
a <- '\u26a5'  # unicode for hermaphrodite/transgendered 
plot(1, 1, pch = a)
dev.off()
```

When I ran your code I actually received an error:

```
Warning messages:
1: In plot.xy(xy, type, ...) :
  conversion failure on '⚥' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <e2>
```

It's interesting you didn't report the same error.

The same issue is observed with ggplot, as it's device/os dependent.

Comment: I installed Cairo and XQuartz https://www.xquartz.org, which is required for Cairo to work properly with macOS. However, I am still getting squares. I managed to get some other unicode to work with a code like `plot(1, 1, pch = '\u25D2', family = "Arial Unicode MS")` ... and I could get the same result without Cairo too.

Comment: I did not get the warning message you mentioned with your code. OTOH, I did get that message when I used pdf instead of cairo_pdf ... the output was three dots (...) instead of hermaphrodite/transgendered symbol.

Comment: There's a good chance we are running different versions of R and sub packages. Without a reproducible example with versions stated there's not much else that can be done.